# Android Geocoder returning empty address

Tags: android, geocoding

I am trying to get location address from Geocoder, I am able to get latitude and longitude  but it returning address with zero length.

Here is my code snippet

```
            double longi = location.getLongitude();
            double latt = location.getLatitude();

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.ENGLISH);

            String add="";
            try {


                List<Address> address = geocoder.getFromLocation(latt/1E6,longi/1E6, 1);


                System.out.println("in location listener "+address.size());


                int i=0;

                if(address.size()>0)
                {
                    for(i=0;i<address.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex();i++)
                    {
                        add += address.get(0).getAddressLine(i);
                    }


                    Toast toast  = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                    toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), add, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }   

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Please help me to get it correct. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Have a look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9075559/593709)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Geocoder query methods will return an empty list if there no backend service in the platform. Use the isPresent() method to determine whether a Geocoder implementation exists.

See the [Geocoder documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) for more information.

Comment: I've never had a pleasant experience with the Geocoder API. But this is your best bet.

Comment: I have tried `getFromLocationName()` with different addresses. For some address I am getting result but for some addresses I am getting an array of size **0**.

Comment: I am already checking the Geocoder.isPresent() and this static function is returning true. Yet I am getting empty address list

Answer (score 0):

I think your project isn't targeting the correct AVD. To use geolocation you have to make it point an avd implementing the google APIs. Once You changed it everything will work  fine.

[Installing the Google APIs Add-On](https://developers.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/installing?hl=fr-FR)