# geocoder.getFromLocation returning null

Tags: android, location, android-location, google-geocoder

my code :

```
                 try
                {

                            Geocoder geocoder;
                        List<Address> addresses;

            geocoder = new Geocoder(LocationActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());

            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(longitude,latitude,1);

            Toast.makeText(LocationActivity.this, addresses.size() + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);

            Toast.makeText(LocationActivity.this, address + "  " + city + " " + country, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(LocationActivity.this,e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

this is my code to get address from longitude and latitude.
but every time addresses.size returns 0

can anyone help me for this

Comment: [Have a look at this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9075559/593709)

Comment: Check for the permissions

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" ></uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" ></uses-permission>
 
and also test it on a real device rather than emulator

Comment: thanx :) but i m using android api : 8

Comment: i m using samsung device

Comment: i have already added both permissions

Comment: then maybe there is a problem the way you are getting the latitude and logitute

Comment: latitude and longitude are perfect.. i tried it on google earth..

Comment: How did you intialize lat and long ?

Comment: i got lat long using locationManager and its perfect.. i checked it

Answer (score 2):

I find the solution...
hold `Ctrl` on `getFromLocation()` and go to `Geocoder.class` .
then download sources for your android API and restart your project.
then you see its work

Answer (score 0):

if you are using emulator go to DDMS you will find emulator control and give your valid lat lng in that and press send.. 
and Batter make sure that mention Internet permissions in manifest...

```
    try {
        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses;

        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

        double longitude = 23.00000;
        double latitude = 72.00000;
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(longitude, latitude, 1);

        Toast.makeText(this, addresses.size() + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
        String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
        String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);

        if(address==null)
        address="";
        if(city==null)
            city="";
        if(country==null)
            country="";

        Toast.makeText(this, address + "  " + city + " " + country,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: check your lat long valid or not

Comment: i checked it... and its valid

Comment: finally try with targetsdk version 15

Comment: nope... whats thats... can u give a full description.. my api is 8 and android 2.2

Comment: but i m creating my application in targetsdk 8 (2.2)... now what i have to do ??

Comment: Right click on project, go to properties(in the end), select the android at right side , select project-build target (sel max) which contain google,  and mention this in manifest <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15"
         /> ..... if still it is not working , may be ur device fault

Comment: but my device have android 2.2 OS.. if i change target then still i can run this app in android 2.2 ?

Comment: yes u can run it, target sdk is not a matter make sure that min sdk is 8 so u can run in 2.2

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

Comment: i change the target to 15 and i tried to other device... still not working... still its give arrayIndexOutofBound Exception..

Comment: have you start location access from settings

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this will help, but I think you are getting an IOException. Look at the LogCat. Also see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation%28double,%20double,%20int%29)

Comment: nope.. i m not getting any exception... but addresses size always 0

Answer (score 0):

The Geocoder query methods will return an empty list if there no backend service in the platform.

ref - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

Comment: so how to install the backend service

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with a condtion address.size() > 0 in the try loop.

I didn't really found out where the real problem is , but it seems that the loop is happening twice, and once too early , because i could have the loop happened twice , one empty result and one good result.

Maybe coming from me as as two map and date passing through intent. 
But fixed for me